# How accurately can you define the characteristics of a finger on a touch screen device?

Tags: security

Could you build a finger print reader with current phone technology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If you could [this would not make any sense](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/08/apple-wanted-authentecs-new-technology-asap-for-future-products/)